# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

Estou aprendendo Java e sei basicamente o que significa NullPointerException. Mas gostaria de entender o porque isso ocorre.

Esse é o código da Activity:

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FamilyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_family);

        //Instantiate an ArrayList
        final ArrayList<Words> famillyArray = new ArrayList<Words>( );

        //Supply Array
        famillyArray.add(new Words("father", "әpә", R.drawable.family_father, R.raw.family_father));
        famillyArray.add(new Words("mother", "әṭa", R.drawable.family_mother, R.raw.family_mother));
        famillyArray.add(new Words("son", "angsi", R.drawable.family_son, R.raw.family_son));
        famillyArray.add(new Words("daughter", "tune", R.drawable.family_daughter, R.raw.family_daughter));
        famillyArray.add(new Words("older brother", "taachi", R.drawable.family_older_brother, R.raw.family_older_brother));
        famillyArray.add(new Words("younger brother", "chalitti", R.drawable.family_younger_brother, R.raw.family_younger_brother));
        famillyArray.add(new Words("older sister", "teṭe", R.drawable.family_older_sister, R.raw.family_older_sister));
        famillyArray.add(new Words("younger sister", "kolliti", R.drawable.family_younger_sister, R.raw.family_younger_sister));
        famillyArray.add(new Words("grandmother ", "ama", R.drawable.family_grandmother, R.raw.family_grandmother));
        famillyArray.add(new Words("grandfather", "paapa", R.drawable.family_grandfather, R.raw.family_grandfather));

        final WordsAdapter famillyAdapter = new WordsAdapter(this, famillyArray, R.color.category_family);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(famillyAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener( ) {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l ) {
                Words getSong = famillyArray.get(position);
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(FamilyActivity.this, getSong.getSongResource());
                releaseMediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.start();
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener( ) {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion( MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ) {
                        releaseMediaPlayer();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    private void releaseMediaPlayer(){
        if (mediaPlayer != null){
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Note essa linha do código acima, está no segundo @Override:

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(FamilyActivity.this, getSong.getSongResource());
```

O erro é resolvido por simplesmente colocar `MediaPlayer` da variável `mediaPlayer` ficando assim `MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = Media...`

Mas o que eu não entendo é: Se eu já instanciei a variável como um objeto da classe MediaPlayer no começo da Activity, por que tenho que declarar novamente? Se você olhar atentamente, na primeira linha após `public class FamillyActivy extends AppCompatActivity {` ela já está declarada.

Obrigado por qualquer ajuda que me faça entender a lógica desse erro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro não está em declarar a variável `mediaPlayer` dentro ou fora do método `onItemClick`.

O erro está no método `releaseMediaPlayer`. Observe que esse método é chamado **após** você instanciar o objeto `MediaPlayer` na variável global de mesmo nome.

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(FamilyActivity.this, getSong.getSongResource());
releaseMediaPlayer();
```

Agora observe que o método `releaseMediaPlayer` está, simplesmente, atribuindo à variável global `mediaPlayer`, o valor de `null`.

Esse método está removendo a instância que você "acabou de fazer" antes de acessa-lo.

```
private void releaseMediaPlayer(){
    if (mediaPlayer != null){
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null; /* O erro é devido essa linha tornar a variável `mediaPlayer` nula depois de ter sido instanciada */
    }
}
```

Quando você defini a variável `mediaPlayer` dentro do método `onItemClick`, você deixa de usar a variável global e passa a usar uma variável local.

E como uma variável local não pode ser alterada ou acessada fora do método onde ela foi definida, o método `releaseMediaPlayer` não consegue torna-la nula *(enviando o erro `NullPointerException`)*.

Apesar do erro está em `mediaPlayer.start();`, ele **só é causado pois a variável está sendo definida como nula no método já citado**

Comment: @MarcusDacorréggio mas o erro é devido a linha torna-la nula depois de ter sido instancia. Editei minha resposta para ficar mais claro o conteúdo que escrevi logo abaixo do código.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger sim vai gerar, mas como eu expliquei na minha resposta. O erro está acontece **justamente** por ele instancia o objeto MediaPlayer, torna-lo nula na função `releaseMediaPlayer` e depois tentar utilizar o método `start` em uma variável que foi instancia e depois definida como nula novamente.

Comment: Vadeir voce tem razão. Obrigado por explicar o o problema de forma clara. Foi bastante util pra mim. Eu estava programando a horas e já estava bem cansado, acabei deixando passar despercebido. Mas uma vez, obrigado pela ajuda!